# Primality test for numbers of the form $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Here is what I observed :

Inspired by Lucas-Lehmer primality test, I think I made a primality test for numbers of the form $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ but the test isn't perfect and there are some conditions to apply :

- $a$ must not be a perfect power otherwise you can get false positive.
- $p$ must be a prime number $\ge 3$ otherwise you can "break" the primality test and get false positive.

Interestingly the test passes some strong pseudoprimes, Poulet number, Carmichael number or Wieferich primes.

Let $N = \frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$

Let the sequence $S_i = 2 \cdot T_{a}(S_{i-1}/2)$ where $T_{n}(x)$ is the Chebyshev's polynomial of the first kind with $S_0 = 4$.

Then $N$ is prime if $S_{p} \equiv 2 \cdot T_{a}(2)$ (mod $N$) or $S_{p} \equiv 2 \cdot T_{a-2}(2)$ (mod $N$)

You can run the test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjkEKgzAQRfeeYnCV2IgYLF2k0xvUjVspRI0YUBM0rRQ8fFNLoQU3w8z_j-FJPAooS4iG--xgNA4qBRKsmlpVO7BmUVMUWMxOP5hH7KQHD44NXIBHQY5E3myc0oRIP0VQ4NU0JGO532s3YSqCpdO9Iv44o2UF8siavu5U9Zw79SCSpaxIOBUeOOD7hW5JgXsYp-u608R865hXGx3586HiE4abdvhlwtoM1sza-YiKFz6AUXw=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) (outdated, see below for new test).

For the moment, I didn't find a counterexample with the two conditions.

I need help for proving it but I don't know how to start.
If you found a counterexample please tell me.

EDIT : I made a new test, you can found it [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNkMEKwjAMhu-C7xB2areKbCgeanwDvew6hK52rLCtZauK4MMbJ8IEES8J_8_3JyQK1xKKAuL2PAToXIDSgAJv-sroAN5dTR_PZx5XmwlHjO9tS2R3gh1kRByQqaNfpHzJFFU5n-W4dydW2dJ1Sms72slEJikXhyeoQ48p9WttG8NIbdGLHLPYu0bXprwNtbkwJVKRLzMuCUhw3GArluM37vdWTlPu9y_JRfZXVtDtXWAf93L5MqPxL9GbibRrvRtsIIvLB4cIbyU=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) (outdated)

I just changed $S_0$ is now equals to $L_n$ where $L_n$ is the $n$th Lucas number and I changed the final value of the sequence, and it seems it removes some false positive.

EDIT 2 : I made a new test,for $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ you can found it [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtzsEKwjAMBuC74DuEndpZkQ3FQ41v4C69itBtlQ3cGraqCHt441RQ2CUhyUf4LW40HI8QN9c-QOsD5A4skOvOrghA_u66eD4jXG9_HBvq6oZlW8IeUhYZCnuiZSJXwnLV85nBgy8Fqew1FKHDhPu9qi9O8LRDUgbTmPylqFz-6Ct3E1YlyqxSqRkscPxSn4XBKUfshmHitkw_V8UZ2yD-ckn9XkZj_uhrosI35Ps68ErqJ45oU0Q=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

This time, $S_0 = p$ and $N$ is prime if $S_{p} \equiv 2 \cdot T_{a}(p/2)$ (mod $N$) or $S_{p} \equiv 2 \cdot T_{a-2}(p/2)$ (mod $N$) and it removes again some false positives.

If you found again a counterexample, please tell me.

Comment: I've added a counterexample for the test in EDIT2. I suggest you to make some more extensive testing (e.g., for all $a,p\leq 100$) before publishing new "tests".

Comment: This test reduces to simply checking that $(a^p-1)/(a-1)$ is a Fermat probable prime to a certain quadratic integer base. It does not prove Primality.

Answer (score 10):

The test fails already for $p=3$ and $a=7$, claiming that $57=3\cdot 19$ is prime.

**ADDED.** And new test fails for $a=10$ and $p=5$.

**ADDED#2.** And the test in EDIT 2 fails for $a=52$ and $p=3$.

Comment: Nice observation, I will try to improve the test, if it's improvable of course. It seems it fails sometimes when $N < T_{a}(2) \cdot 2$

Comment: Here you are encountering ala Lucas pseudoprimes of a special form. Unless numbers of this form are very sparse (like in your previous question), you'll have some false positives (ie. composites passing the test).

Comment: Claim: Grothendieck [used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_(number)) this test.

Comment: I edited my question and now it seems than some false positive are now gone. If you found again some false positive or negative. Please tell me

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I don't know, do you have some paper about that ?

Comment: Grothendieck famously [claimed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_(number)) that $57$ is prime - maybe he used your test.

Comment: @kijinSeija: See updated answer for a counterexample to your new test.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: [What to do when the trisector comes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225381383_What_to_do_when_the_trisector_comes).

Comment: @user21820: Nice article! Still, I find it quite entertaining to look for counterexamples and to understand the reason why or why not it is easy to find them.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: It's entertaining when you *do* find them, yes? Just like the author of that article does for fake trisections. =P

Answer (score 2):

Following Max Alekseyev suggestions. The following Pari GP code provides false positives. You can play with limits $p$ and $a$ inside forprime and for loops respectively (last statement).

```
phi(a,p)= 
{ 
my(N=(a^p-1)/(a-1), S=Mod(p,N), ctr=1); 
while(ctr<=p,S=2*polchebyshev(a,1,S/2);ctr+=1); 
if((S==2*polchebyshev(a,1,p/2)||S==2*polchebyshev(a-2,1,p/2))!=isprime(N),print("a=",a," p=",p," ",N)) 
}
forprime(p=3,200,for(a=3,5000,if(ispower(a),next(),phi(a,p))))
```

The following are false positives for $2<p<200$ and $2<a<5001$

```
a=52 p=3 2757
a=82 p=3 6807
a=103 p=3 10713
a=222 p=3 49507
a=260 p=3 67861
a=296 p=3 87913
a=315 p=3 99541
a=442 p=3 195807
a=466 p=3 217623
a=664 p=3 441561
a=675 p=3 456301
a=764 p=3 584461
a=1152 p=3 1328257
a=1640 p=3 2691241
a=1683 p=3 2834173
a=1785 p=3 3188011
a=2226 p=3 4957303
a=2422 p=3 5868507
a=2944 p=3 8670081
a=3601 p=3 12970803
a=3840 p=3 14749441
a=4674 p=3 21850951
```

It seems that false positives are found just for $p=3$. You can improve your test by OR-ing more conditions to exclude $p=3$ falses first, then $p=5$ (if there is any) and so on.

**NOTE** Code was modified as it is indicated in comments. Output list too.

Comment: You are right, I just excluded perfect squares. Thanks for pointing this out. I will modify the code asap.

Comment: also $a=343=7^3$

Comment: Done. Thanks @MaxAlekseyev.